# Android Studio Focus-Switch to ClassFile

Tags: android, android-studio

in Android Studio I see my classes on the left (Android-Tab) and the editor window with the open class file (SomeClass.java) on the right.

If I double click a class file in the Android-Tab, it gets opened and the focus switches to the class file. I can start writing immediately.

My problem is: If I select a class file in the Android-Tab and hit 'Enter', the class file opens but the focus is still in the Android-Tab and I can not start writing. I have to use the mouse/trackpad to click into the class file to switch the focus.

Is it possible to change the behaviour of Android Studio in that case?

I use Android Studio 2.3 beta 2 on OSX.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Comment: The accepted answer still works for me (Android Studio 4.1.1). Open the keymap and search for "jump to source". In my case the keys are F3 or Enter. Then you can re-assign the keys if you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Command(⌘)+Down Arrow(↓)` to **(Open | Switch)&Focus** the class instead of pressing **Enter** which only **(Opens | Switch)** the class.

On **Keymap** you can find `Jump to Source`:
[image]

Comment: It is not working for me. Do you know the name of the command in the key map?